# Attempt to get node but dynatree tree don't reload completely yet

Tags: dynatree, jquery-dynatree

Everybody hi

Have such script template

tree.reload()
tree.activateKey();

so, it reloads tree and then get focus for special node.

But get such situation - activateKey starts when tree is reloading and don't get node we need because it doesn't load yet...

how it could be fixed? how launch activateKey when tree guaranted reloaded completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to call activateKey() in the onPostInit event.